# Excel If statement with And operator

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, subroutine

I am migrating a complex excel macro to Java code.
I have a code snippet as below in VBA. Could you please help in understanding the structure of this if block(expression). Thanks.

Here nLen is some positive integer.

```
If ((nLen - 1) And &H1) <> 0 Then
   //some code here
End If
```

Comment: `And` is the bitwise AND operator. `&H1` is the hexadecimal literal 1. So the condition tests whether `nLen - 1` is odd, or whether `nLen` is even.

Comment: @jsheeran I find your comment more like the answer of the question, why not post it as an answer?, _Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`And` is the bitwise AND operator. `&H` is the prefix for a hexadecimal literal, so `&H1` is 1. This is equivalent to `(nLen - 1) Mod 2`.

So, in a very roundabout way, what this code does is to check whether `nLen` is even.